# Current topics on Radio Astronomy and looking for advice

Tags: radio-astronomy, radio-telescope, radio

Background and Question: I'm an undergraduate student interested on Radio Astronomy. I consider myself enthusiastic about it and I project myself following this "path" so I'd like, apologizing myself if this is a naive question, to ask you, more experienced astronomers, **what are the current topics being part of research in Radio Astronomy**.

My thoughts:

- I know Cosmology and CMB Measurements are something that will keep its route for a long time as huge projects continue being developed.
- Also I'd say Radio-loud Galaxies are something that Radio Astronomers are putting lots of work into.
- Interferometric techniques, data reduction algorithms and image synthesis.
- Astro-Chemistry and the study of spectral lines using data cubes such as provided by ALMA.

More questions:

- Am I wrong with any of the topics listed? What else is being done now?
- How do you see this in the next 5 - 10 - 20 years ?
- Considering I want to work on my thesis project this year, what would you recommend (or to other undergrad. students) ? What would be a "good route" to follow after graduating? (my grades to this date are at ~ 80%).

Comment: radio emissions from other solar system planets, especially Jupiter

Comment: [My question on the relevance of different radio bands](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43508/37191) is somewhat related. I see a lot of potential in citizen science (also for radioastronomy), e.g. actively engaging laypersons to contribute to (radio) astronomy. I am saying this not only because of my appreciation for [SETI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_for_extraterrestrial_intelligence), but also in general. In metereology, the massive increase of weather stations operated by private persons helped improving high-resolution weather models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples that you can read about within Astronomy SE and Space SE:

#### [Time Domain Astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_astronomy) (link)

e.g. [LOFAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-Frequency_Array_(LOFAR)) and (as it turns out) [CHIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Hydrogen_Intensity_Mapping_Experiment). Think better [FRB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_radio_burst) detection gravitational lensing effects on pulsar timing (needs several questions of its own)

- [Why did it take five years to "figure out" how to use astrometric calibration sources to deblur LOFAR images?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36862/7982)
- [Open dataset from antenna array](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33574/7982)

and

- [How tightly clustered are the CHIME-detected FRB repeats?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29129/7982)
- [What are the challenges for the building and data analysis of the CHIME telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29167/7982)
- [How does Canada's radiotelescope CHIME manage polarization-dependent apodization of the fast f/0.25 optics?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28615/7982)
- [What will succeed the Arecibo Observatory?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39948/7982)

also

- [What exactly is interplanetary scintillation; what was the Interplanetary Scintillation Array looking for? Did it successfully observe any?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34532/7982)

#### Space based, and Satellite VLBI

- Far Side of the Moon stuff, e.g. Chang'e 4: [The NCLE on the orbiter and the LFS on the lander work in synergy performing low-frequency (0.1–80 MHz) radio astronomical observations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_4#Relay_satellite)
- [What can be learned from low frequency radio astronomy available outside of Earth's ionosphere?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34412/7982)
- [Has VLBI been done using any space-based receivers besides Spektr-R?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35642/12102) (Space SE)
- [What's the status and timeline for Millimetron? (Russia's 10m Deployable Antenna cooled to 6 K Earth-Space VLBI)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46490/12102) (Space SE)
- [What are Spectr-R's major contributions to radio astronomy that could not have been done from Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33564/12102) (Space SE)
- [How is Spektr-R doing these days?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35641/12102) (Space SE)
- [Has VLBI been done using any space-based receivers besides Spektr-R?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35642/12102) (Space SE)
- [What kind of ground-based radio astronomy is NASA's DSN used for? Who are the PIs?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32911/12102) (Space SE)
- [Are images of exoplanets' surfaces technically possible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31768/12102) (Space SE)
- [Could a radio telescope orbit Earth-Moon L2 so that it is in the Moon's radio shadow?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26751/12102)
- Rotating liquid mirror on the Moon: [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/41027/7982) to *Why can't we build a huge stationary optical telescope inside a depression similar to the FAST?*

#### Fancy, complicated focal plane arrays and techniques

- [How would a Fast Fourier Transform Telescope work without a mirror, dish or lenses?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32014/7982)
- [How do ASKAP's focal plane phased array feeds interact with the entire array phasing?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/21121/7982)
- [What is the highest granularity focal-plane array on a dish radio telescope? Or is this the ONLY ONE?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16237/7982)
- [Would Adaptive Optics be Useful in Radio Astronomy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13930/7982)
- [Has radio astronomy ever been done on objects that appear very close to the Moon? Is this avoided?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35590/7982)

#### [Radar Astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_astronomy) (link)

- [What are recent discoveries with Earth-based radar telescopes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41198/7982)
- [What will succeed the Arecibo Observatory?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39948/7982)
- [What causes "North-South ambiguity" when doppler radar imaging a planet surface equator on?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30256/7982)
- https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22493/12102
- [What is the physical geometry of this apparent "eclipse" of a tiny moon of Asteroid Florence?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22480/7982)
- [Farthest distance to a solar system object that's been measured by radar?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37752/12102) (Space SE)
- [How did Arecibo detect methane lakes on Titan, and image Saturn's rings?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33023/7982) (Space SE)
- [Why is Saturn invisible in this radar image of its rings?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33060/7982) (Space SE)
- [Why was the 100m Green Bank dish needed together with DSN's 70m Goldstone dish to detect Chandrayaan-1 in lunar orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20582/12102) (Space SE, not exactly Astronomy but pretty cool from an instrumentation and signals point of view)
- [Why are Titan's lakes “black” in radar images rather than transparent?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30747/12102) (Space SE)
- [Is delay-doppler radar imaging of NEO asteroids possible only if it spins fast enough?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21158/12102) (Space SE)
- [Separating fact from fiction, how to get from this radar image to this GIF?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36359/12102) (Space SE)